# Error "[ShareSheet] connection invalidated" error iOS13+ but not on iOS 11.4

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-sharesheet

I want to share a file using the Share Sheet and have written code that seems to work just fine. However I keep seeing these error messages in the log (using Xcode 11.3)

```
[ShareSheet] connection invalidated
```

I have two physical devices I'm testing on; an iPad running iOS 13.1.2 and an iPhone 6 running 11.4. I don't see these messages on the iPhone with the older iOS on it.  Both cases the sharing seems to work just fine.  Here's the code I'm using using text instead of a file:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["simple text for test"], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [.message, .airDrop]
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = myBarButtonItem           
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The message shows up when the share sheet goes away (either because user completes an action, or they tap outside of it to cancel).

Is it safe to ignore these messages?  It's just odd that they didn't show up in the older OS but do in the new one.

Edited on 20 Mar 2020: I validated that I was providing a valid source or barButtonItem. I've changed the code to match that where I'm using a UIBarButtonItem and I still see the ShareSheet connection invalidated error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. And some users claim that the share sheet won't show up. But my test device is working well.

Answer (score 10):

I got

> [ShareSheet] connection invalidated

in the Xcode output log on iOS 13.x, and the share sheet was squished and did not have any buttons in it.

To fix it, assign your `sourceView` to something more specific than `self.view`

In my case, I had some `UILabels` near the top of my view, so I set my `sourceView` to one of those.  For example, in my parent view controller, I had a `UILabel` named `labelCustomerName` so I used that:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.labelCustomerName
```

Comment: I've seen the squished window too when I don't give it a specific button. I've modified my example to be correct (I was using a barButtonItem and had included the wrong code). Still seeing the Share Sheet connection invalidated error.

Comment: FYI, using navigationController?.navigationBar works as well (if your VC is embedded in a navigation controller, of course)

Comment: oh boy you saved my time , not sure why it is happening

Answer (score 4):

For me, it was solved when i added this code, based on [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller).

```
activityViewController.isModalInPresentation = true
```

By the way, it seems like even if press the close button for the activity it still shows that message.

Comment: This got rid of the message for me, but did not fix that the share sheet was empty.  Interestingly, If I close and open the share sheet, on the third time it works.

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(filename)
        
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)
        present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```